# how to get the length scale, length unit, energy scale and energy unit from a EELS map data by DM script

Tags: dm-script

[image]I want to get length scale, length unit,  energy scale, and energy unit from an EELS map data by DM script

```
 source.ImageGetDimensionCalibration(0, sOrig, sScale, sUnit, 0)
source.ImageGetDimensionCalibration(2, eOrig, eScale, eUnit, 0)
```

The above codes did not work, it always make the energy unit with 1eV

For example, an EELS data with dispersion 0.9 ev/pixel, or 0.5 ev/pixel, and the energy range from 0 to 400, and the EELS map is 10nm x8nm, I need to get all this information with DM script.

Now the bug of my code is it always count the disepersion is 1 ev/pixel

Any suggestions, thanks

Comment: Please provided more information, in particular to the image you want to read from. The commands are correct (to get the information along X and Z axis of the data.) What is the actual calibration of the data? (You can provide a screenshot of the imageDisplay info dialog on the calibration tab.)

Comment: thank you. I added a picture and detailed questions, please help!

Comment: The picture you have added is a 1D spectrum. If this is your image "source" then the first line of your code should return: Unit=eV with the scale/origin. The second line of your code does not apply, as there is no 3rd dimension in this data. 
If you put the SpectrumImage as "source", then your script would be ok, returning the spatial calibration in the first line, and the eV calibration in the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will hopefully clear up any questions:

```c
void PrintCalibrations(image source)
{
    number nDim = source.ImageGetNumDimensions()
    result("\n '[" + source.ImageGetLabel() +"]:"+ source.ImageGetName() +"' calibrations:")
    result("\n Data has " + nDim + " dimensions.")
    for( number d=0; d<nDim; d++ )
    {
        string unit_dim
        number scale_dim, origin_dim
        source.ImageGetDimensionCalibration(d, origin_dim, scale_dim, unit_dim, 0)
        result("\n\t Dimension #"+d+": scale = "  + scale_dim + " \t origin = " + origin_dim + " \t [" + unit_dim + "]" )
    }
}

// Pick your data by image letter!
Image SIdata_3D := B
Image PickerSpectrum_1D := A
Image elementalMap_2D := D

ClearResults()
PickerSpectrum_1D.PrintCalibrations()
elementalMap_2D.PrintCalibrations()
SIdata_3D.PrintCalibrations()
```

Applied to a test data set:
[image: Example]

Comment: Not sure the reason,  the script keeps to recognize EELS spectrum images (that are 3D)  as "has 2 dimensions"

Comment: @together Can you enter the Image Info dialog (CTRL+D) of that image and verify its calibrations? Also: Can you upload that data to some place I can access it, then I would take a look for myself. I doubt that the problem you have is with the script, it sounds rather like a misconception of the data.

Comment: could I communicate with you by email? that will be good for me

Comment: @together StackOverflow doesn't have a private-message system, but if you let somehow know your email, I will contact you.